# What is the best PHP API to ImageMagick?

Tags: php, api, imagemagick, imagick

I use Imagick extension, but it doesn't give all common options form ImageMagick. Some methods doesn't work or doesn't work properly (like getImageWidth, getFormat, setGravity...).
So what with another API's like MagickWand or phMagick? Anyone check 'em all? What Your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively sure all the PHP ImageMagick libraries work on top of the Imagick extension.

Another option would be to use exec or such to run the command-line image magick tool if that provides more features.